# Rainbow Tables: Why do we need to store the last value of a chain?

Tags: passwords, rainbow-table

Surely we could just make it so a rainbow table says for each beginning of chain do 10k iterations, and then we wouldn't have to store both values?

Or does by doing it this way stop collisions?

Comment: If you only store the first value, what do you gain from the rainbow table over plain password guessing?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of rainbow tables is incorrect. But isn't rainbow tables essentially a bruteforce attack anyway? And you would be giving the chains a length, just not having to store the end value...

Comment: *Generating* a rainbow table is essentially a brute-force attack. *Searching* a rainbow table is not. You look at each chain end to quickly see if the password you seek can be part of that chain. The gain of a rainbow table is that you don't need to compute a chain if the end of the chain doesn't fit your target hash.

Comment: So you reduce and hash the given hash and check each value against all the chain endings until you find a match or go over the chain length (in which case you won't find the password in the rainbow table), then go through that specific chain until you find the hash?

Comment: @Ben Pretty much. You start from the recovered hash, and construct a chain from there; that only requires making one chain, which you can very quickly check against all the precomputed chain ends to find out what chain the original hash was in (without having to store the whole chains).